# Ubercart need to pay depends on user role

Tags: ubercart

I am using drupal 6.20 and Ubercart 2.0
Like what I asked in the subject.
Is there any chance that I can customize a ordering process with or without payment?

For example:
There are 2 roles of users ( Role A and Role B)
Users of Role A need to pay all my products to complete the transaction.
Users of Role B don't need to pay any of my products to complete the transaction.

Actually I want my website to be suitable for 2 kinks of clients:
1. wholesalers (Role A) --- order online but pay through company invoicing system
2. retailers (Role B) --- order online and pay instantly

Appreciate any thoughts and helps on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been **solved** and just want to put the solution here to help someone has the same interests!

Download the uc_purchase_order module, http://drupal.org/project/uc_po

And give the permission to the user role you want them to purchase through purchase order.

Comment: how can this be achieved with drupal 7 as the module listed UC Purchase Order does not have a drupal 7 version